# Pass checkout info in a github actions script

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a self-hosted github runner that launches python script.  This python script runs a bash shell script on a different machine, and I think I can pass arguments to either script.  Right now, I have set it up to clone the `main` branch of my repo, or I can pass it an argument to check out a different branch.  This works great for testing when tags are issued.

I want to set this up so that it will test the code in a `pull_request`.  The `pull_request`s come from forks of the repository, not branches within the repository.  My understanding is that the SHA won't be available in the repo because it only exists on the fork, so I *can't* do something like

```
git clone <URL>.FMS.git && cd FMS && git merge $GITHUB_SHA
```

**How do I pass the information from the fork and fork's branch/SHA to merge into the `main` branch in the repository?** I can then set my script to do (?)

```
git clone <URL>/FMS.git && cd FMS && git pull <FORK-URL>/FMS.git $GITHUB_SHA
```

Here is how I have my workflow currently set up

```yaml
on: pull_request
jobs:
   pw:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, pwp]
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      max-parallel: 2
      matrix:
        include:
                - runname: FMS with intel 18
                  runscript: python3 /home/pw/storage/pw_api_python/FMStestStartClusters.py cluster
                - runname: FMS with intel 2021 container
                  runscript: python3 /home/pw/storage/pw_api_python/FMSintel21StartClusters.py cluster_two
    steps:
                - name: FMS make check
                  env:
                          RUNNAME: ${{ matrix.runname }}
                          RUNSCRIPT: ${{ matrix.runscript }}
                  run: $RUNSCRIPT
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to set this up so that it will test the code in a pull_request. The pull_requests come from forks of the repository, not branches within the repository.

This part is right, but:

> My understanding is that the SHA won't be available in the repo because it only exists on the fork

... this part isn't: the act of making a pull request, on GitHub, transfers<sup>1</sup> the PR's commits into the target repository.  You should be able to access them by hash ID, and you can use the `refs/pull` namespace to access them as well.

I don't know the GitHub actions part of any of this, but if you wanted to get those commits into your own clone on your laptop, you would run:

```
git fetch origin refs/pull/123/head:refs/heads/pr123
```

for instance and you would suddenly now have a branch `pr123` on your laptop, holding those commits.  (This assumes `origin` is the remote name for your repository on GitHub, to which the PR was made.)

---

<sup>1</sup>These are sort of virtualized operations, using Git's internal alternates mechanism, I believe, though I've never actually worked for GitHub themselves.

Comment: This was very helpful.  I was able to pass the variable $GITHUB_REF instead of $GITHUB_SHA, and then fetch the reference (your refs/heads/pr123) and merge it in with `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.  This is exactly what I needed to do.  Thank you.